# Get Product Url return 404 in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to get product's url so i use `getProductUrl()` in result its return a `url` that seems be correct but its not ,When I want to open it ,the store return 404 not found error.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$url => $product->getProductUrl();

//It's return

// http://mg1.dev/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/905/s/plaid-cotton-shirt-royal-blue-l/
```

Comment: Check this out may be it's going to help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/product-getproducturl-giving-url-path-without-url-key

Answer (score 0):

I got same error with you, here is my sollotion.

Add following line to your Query:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'neq'=>"1" )));
```

IN my case that solved the 404/wrong url.

Answer (score -2):

Check your catalog product model is really returning values or not...
If it is returning values, still you are not getting product url, then try with sku...

try this,

```
$sku = 'test'; // SKU you want to load.

$url =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku)->getProductUrl();
echo $url;
```

Comment: Yes i got url but its not true ,, the site return 404 , i added an exmple of url that codes reture @ravi-mule